# Pasar un array en un input por Post en php

Tags: php, array, post

tengo este pequeño formulario que me arroja una serie de códigos pero no estoy recibiendo bien el array :

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="row float-right">
<input type="hidden" name="SucursalID" value="<?echo $id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="CodigosArray" value="<? echo $ArrayCodigos ?>">
<input type="submit" style="position: relative ;" class="btn btn-primary position-realtive end-50" value="Agregar todos los productos" >
</div>
</form>
```

y lo recibo con un if hice un pequeño foreach para solo ver los datos que arroja pero este no funciona dado a que el array no se manada:

```
if (isset($_POST['CodigosArray'])) {
   $codigos = $_POST['CodigosArray'];
   foreach($codigos as $row){
       echo $row;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un array es un objeto de PHP, HTML no soporta ese tipo de datos. Una forma de enviarlo es [serializando](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) el array.

-Edit- Me di cuenta que debido a la codificación de la serialización, HTML no escapa correctamente las comillas. Una forma de resolverlo podría ser convirtiéndo la cadena a [base64](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php).

```
<input type="hidden" name="CodigosArray" value="<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($ArrayCodigos));?>">
```

Y luego lo obtienes revirtiendo:

```
$codigos = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['CodigosArray']));
```

PD. Puedes también probar con `json_encode`/`json_decode` en vez de la serialización. Y con [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) en vez de base64.